# Calculating variance of joint pdf.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

I am having problem in settling the domain. I usually draw graph in these type of question but can't.
$0<|x_1|\leq x_2<\infty$
If $x_1$ is greater than zero whats the point of modulus? Plus integral is scary.

Comment: I have to follow normal method of calculating Variance no trick here? $V(X_1)=E(X_1)^{2} - (E(X_1))^{2}$

Comment: Better brackets:  $V(X_1)=E(X_1^2) - (E(X_1))^{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints

- $X_2$ is almost surely positive.
- $-X_2 \le X_1 \le X_2$ and indeed given $X_2=x_2$, you have $X_1$ conditionally uniformly distributed on $[-x_2,x_2]$
- $E[X_1]$ should be obvious
- Law of total variance: $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)] + \operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{E}[Y\mid X])$
- $\int \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x}\,dx$ may be horrible, but multiplying by $x^2$ you should find  $\int x e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$ much easier

Comment: To calculate $E(X_1)$ we will be multiplying with $x_1$ how will it cancel denominator $x_2$?

Comment: Ohhh the other formula godammit.I got it now .

Comment: Can you solve it for me I ll have an idea how to these types next time ?